# c# how to convert PNG / JPG to TGA 32bit?

Tags: c#, image

```
        private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Bitmap original = new Bitmap(@"filepath.cover.png");
          Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
          using (Graphics conv = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
          {
            conv.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
          }
        }
```

Hello everyone, i need some help.

I trying to convert PNG or JPEG files to TGA 32bit files and save them, I am still new to programming and could not find an answer here. I found only this code snip here and tried to get him to run, i tried alot of versions to get an output file, but nothing worked, sometimes I got a blank file, sometimes a corrupt one

thank you to everyone who helps me.

Edit:
First of all, thank you, I tried your code and it gives me an empty file. I'm just trying this:

```
private void TgaConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TGA original = new TGA(@"file.path.cover.png");
    TGA clone = new TGA(original.Width, original.Height, TgaPixelDepth.Bpp32,
    TgaImageType.Uncompressed_TrueColor);

    using (??? conv = ???(clone))
    {
        conv.???(original, new ???(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
        clone.Save(@"file.path.cover.tga");
    }
}
```

at the places with "???" I can't get any further

Comment: You have a problem indeed, TGA is not natively supported. Check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f50e820-f3f1-45dc-8e08-840b430738a2/viewing-tga-images?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it:

```
using TGASharpLib;
....
TGA T;
private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Bitmap original = new Bitmap("file.path.jpg"))
        using (Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(original))
        using (Bitmap newbmp = clone.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        T = (TGA)newbmp;
        T.Save("file.path.cover.tga");
    }
```

Comment: T = (TGA)newbmp; Here T is not defined and this code doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no write support for TGA included in the .net framefork.
But there are other open source libraries available. Have a look at TGASharpLib from Zelenskyi Alexandr (https://github.com/ALEXGREENALEX/TGASharpLib).

If a apply his sample to your code, then this is the result:

```
using TGASharpLib;
...

private void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tga = new TGA(@"filepath.cover.png");
    tga.Save(@"filepath.cover.tga");        
}
```

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to convert PNG to TGA tested and working.

```
    public static void ConvertPngToTga(string pngFilePath, string tgaFilePath)
    {
        // Load the PNG image into a Bitmap object
        Bitmap pngBitmap = new Bitmap(pngFilePath);

        // Convert the Bitmap object to a TGA object
        TGA tgaImage = TGA.FromBitmap(pngBitmap);

        // Save the TGA object to a file
        tgaImage.Save(tgaFilePath);
    }
```